# Como utilizo una variable de sesión (por ejemplo $_SESSION['usuario'] en una consulta con MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysqli, session

lo que necesito es realizar un Select en Mysql pero donde las condiciones sean el usuario que inició la sesión y un campo en la base de datos pero hasta ahora no lo consigo.

Tengo una tabla donde tengo los registros de un usuario y entre ellos está la empresa a la que pertenece y necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos usando el valor del usuario que inició la sesión y la empresa como mencioné.

Probé con varios ejemplos sin éxito y tampoco encuentro una pregunta anterior que pueda ayudarme a completar lo que necesito.

En mi proyecto ya tengo un proceso de autenticación con roles que funciona correctamente pero necesito añadir esta segunda condición

**Esto es el index donde se muestran los campos para el logueo**

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
  if($_SESSION['usuario']['tipo'] == "Admin"){
    header('Location: php/admin/');
  }else if($_SESSION['usuario']['tipo'] == "Usuario"){
    header('Location: php/usuario/');
  }
}
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="error">
      <div class="container">
        <span>Datos no coinciden. Favor intenta nuevamente.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="main">
          <form action="" id="formlg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,15}" name="userlg" placeholder="Usuario" required>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,15}" name="clavelg" placeholder="Clave" required>
            <input type="submit" class="botonlg form-control btn btn-primary" value="Iniciar Sesión">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Esto corresponde al login.php**

```html
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
  require 'conexion.php';
  sleep(2);  
  session_start();
  
 $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
  
  $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userlg']);
  $clave = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clavelg']);

  if($nueva_consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND clave = ?")){
    $nueva_consulta ->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $clave);
    $nueva_consulta ->execute();
    $resultado = $nueva_consulta->get_result();
  if($resultado ->num_rows == 1){
    $datos = $resultado ->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos;
    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'tipo'=>$datos['tipo']));
  }else{
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>true));
  }
    $nueva_consulta->close();
  }
}

$mysqli -> close();

?>
```

Creo que sería mejor hacer la consulta ya en el login.php pues todo lo que se mostrará en el proyecto estará condicionado por el usuario y la empresa como ya comenté.

Agradezco el tiempo y la atención.

Comment: No termino de entender tu pregunta. Estas pasando dos parametros.. que estarias preguntando exactamente?

Comment: Gracias por responder. A ver si me puedo dar a entender mejor. Lo que necesito es poder hacer una consulta a la base de datos pero añadiendo estas condiciones. Primero el usuario que inició la sesión y segundo la empresa a la que pertenece (hay un campo para esta en la base de datos. No se si aclaro un poco con esto.  Entiendo que el login ahora se hace con el usuario y la clave como suele ser común pero todas las demás consultas en el proyecto deben realizarse también en base al usuario logueado y la empresa.

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, si la info de empresa está en la tabla usuarios añades una tercera condición al where, si está en otra tabla necesitarías hacer un join. Si esta es la pregunta, para poder responder adecuadamente es necesario saber la estructura de la/s tabla/s implicada/s y cómo se relacionan.

Comment: No termino de entender que queres. si todas las otras consultas son usuario/empresa, cual es el problema que tenes? tu primer consulta devuelve la empresa?

Comment: Esta es la tabla como la tengo ahora                                                                                        CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `empresa` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: gbianchi  Las consultas que tengo solo me devuelven usuario y clave .Supongo que es debido a que hay una sesión iniciada pero si en alguna parte del proyecto necesitase hacer una consulta de vuelta solicitando otros valores condicionando también con la empresa creo que es donde estaría el problema. Intenté modificar la consulta que ya tengo en el login agregando una nueva variable para la empresa pero no resultó...

Comment: $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userlg']);
  $clave = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['clavelg']);
 
                                                                                                                                                   if($nueva_consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND clave = ? AND empresa = ?")){
    $nueva_consulta ->bind_param('sss', $usuario, $clave, AQUI ES DONDE NO SE COMO AGREGAR EL DATO PARA COMPLETAR LA CONSULTA );

Comment: En el login.php recibo los valores del usuario y la clave a través de POST pero no se crear condición que haga referencia a la empresa en ese punto. Espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: Tal vez algo como esto  **     $sql = "SELECT empresa FROM usuarios WHERE usuario ='($_SESSION["usuario"])' ";
    **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es guardar el nombre de usuario además de la empresa a la que trabaja para despues usarlas en futuras consultas, ya que serán un condicionante.

Cuando el usuario inicie sesión crea dos variables de sesión, una con el nombre y otra con la empresa:

```html
<?php
  session_start()
  $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userInput];
  $_SESSION['company'] = $_POST['companyInput];
?>
```

Más tarde, para usarlo en consultas en otras páginas .php:

```html
<?php
  session_start()

  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  $company = $_SESSION['company'];

  $con = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = '$user' and company = '$company'"
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Con esto ya pude resolver el problema. Gracias por el tiempo y la paciencia.